# A/B testing differences between US and Australia behaviour

Tags: user-behavior, ab-testing, geolocation

I am running couple of a/b tests on Australia and US, tests are exactly same but results they are showing are totally reverse. Since we tend to move successful A/B tests to be hardcoded on the sites this causes some issues.

Test is performing really well on US but has massive negative impact on Australia. I know that different areas have different online behaviour and preferences but I wouldn't think that discrepancy would be so big. I am kinda tempted to think that there might be an error in our Aus analytics.

Tests are exact duplicates.

Has anyone encountered similar results?
If so what actions you took?

Comment: Mind explaining briefly what the tests are for? I'm wondering if it is something that is very latency dependent, and with AU being further from your servers (guessing) it is giving a much different experience. (i.e. a large hero image may help conversion in US, but if it takes 10secs to load in AU and causes the page to be blank or jump around you'd likely see the opposite)

Comment: The two countries might have the same language - but they do have very different cultures !

Comment: @DasBeasto test was to add accepted payment methods as an image on the cart page and checkout, no functional changes and image is about 140px by 30px at the bottom of the page so I don't think it latency should matter that much. 

PhillipW i know that, but I am wondering if someone else had such contradicting results.

Answer (score 1):

> Tests are exact duplicates.

Same local time of day?

Same average page load?

Same sample size?

Same target audience demographic?

Same experimental setup?

Same language and lexicon?

And is that sample big enough to really call Aus and US variants different?You said the results are different - how different? 75/25 split? Do your [confidence intervals](https://abtestguide.com/calc/) overlap? If they do - you can't be sure your test result is more than a fluke.

Try to prove your assumption wrong. Check the sample size. Check analytics setup. Check the test setup again and make sure there are no other differences. Until you rule out all independent variables besides target country, you can't conclude the result is what you think you're seeing.